# change the size of the text when \input .pdf_tex file generated by Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, size

I am trying to use inkscape to draw mathematical figures. 
Thre are example codes given in [Inkscape manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/File-Export.html#LaTeX_with_Overlay) and to include the PDF file with LaTex overlay (which is generated by file -> save as PDF and choose the option omit text in PDF and generate LaTex file)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\Huge
\def\svgwidth{3.333in}
\input{FileExportText_LaTeX.pdf_tex}

\end{document}
```

and it works.

However, the size of the math expressions in the picture is usually to small or too large. In this document [How to include an SVG image in LaTex](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) , it says "Font type and size do not matter and will not be exported to LATEX". Therefore, I am wondering how to change the text size of every specific math expression generated by Inkscape?

My goal is to draw figures like the great ones in Visual Complex Analysis
[image]. Maybe there is other choice than Inkscape?

Comment: If you use the extension that exports tikz I added  a solution that I suppose that will automate the procedure... But may be not really needed there. So, feel free to ask me delete. [But check if this extension is better for you]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add your desired font size to a specific math expression in the `FileExportText_LaTeX.pdf_tex` file. For example change

```
\put(0.11,0.35603788){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\smash{10}}}%
```

to

```
\put(0.11,0.35603788){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\smash{\large 10}}}%
```

---

Or to get an homogeneous look use the same font size for all the text in the image.

```
{
   \fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont% or whatever fontsize you like
   \def\svgwidth{3.333in}
   \input{FileExportText_LaTeX.pdf_tex}
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It become involved to change the size when there are many mathematical expression in the figure. I am searching for better way to draw figure with many mathhematical expressions. maybe https://github.com/seebk/LaTeXText is another choice.

Comment: @Rikeijin I would try to layout the figure to only use one font size and only change the fontsize for specific elements as a last choice. many different font sizes will make the picture restless...

Comment: May I ask how to change the code in .pdf_tex to lay out the figure with one specific font size?

Comment: @Rikeijin No change required. By default inkscape does not include any fontsize in the .pdf_tex, so everything is set in the fontsize which is currently active in the surrounding document. So choose whatever fontsize in the document before `\include`. In your example, it is `\Huge`

Comment: Like add the enviroment `\begin{large}` ... `\end{large}` around the `\input` line?

Comment: @Rikeijin Yes, or `{   \fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont \input{..}   }` for "arbitrary" fontsizes.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit the solution is about export tikz from the extensions**

A solution with `relsize` package that doesn't need changes in the exported file:

Create the next command in your preamble:

```
\newcommand\scaleInNode[1][1]{\tikzset{execute at begin node={\normalsize\larger[#1]}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\scaleInNode[1][1]{\tikzset{execute at begin node={\normalsize\larger[#1]}}}

\begin{document}
Test text and math before

$f(x)=4\cdot x +1$

\scaleInNode[3]


Test text and math after

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {$f(x)=4\cdot x +1$};
  \node at (5,2) {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Go back to scale 1
\scaleInNode


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {$f(x)=4\cdot x +1$};
  \node at (5,2) {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please do not upvote before test it... I haven't test it due to some problems (I hope a temporary bug) with that extension on my system. If somebody checked it and needed+works .. please inform me. If not needed or doesn't work... Inform me too to delete it

Comment: Thanks, I will devote it after the system lock is relieved. Is there a estenstion for Inkscape to export to tikz? I do not know how tikz works but trying to learn it.

Comment: @Rikeijin, If you are the one who voted up, you don't have to change it... Your options are vote up or vote down... There is not a "take back my vote" here... (A minus would not be really bad if this doesn't work or doesn't needed... but check it first)